# C Using popen to execute cmds on data

Tags: c, winapi, unix, cmd, popen

TL;DR How do you send a string to cmd.exe, execute grep/findstr or sort, and then print the output using popen?

I have a client and server setup. The user enters a command, such as 'list X: | grep name', which is then broken into 'list X:' and 'grep name'. 'list X:' is sent to the server which then executes a list function and returns a char[] containing the list result. The client then needs to feed this into cmd.exe and execute the 'grep name' command on that data and print it out to the user. I don't need to return the data from cmd to the client process, just output it.

I know my code isn't trying to write at the moment (I'm opening the file in read mode) but I had tried a few other things and can't seem to send the data to cmd.exe)

Code is as follows:

```
        ...
        int n = recv(clientSocket, reply, sizeof(reply), 0);

        std::string* cmdStr = new std::string(cmd);
        cmdStr->erase(std::remove(cmdStr->begin(), cmdStr->end(), '\n'), cmdStr->end());

        if(cmdStr->compare("") != 0)    //Something to pipe to command
        {
            char pipeBuffer[8192];
            FILE* pipe;

            char c [8192];
            strcat(c, "cmd.exe /C ");
            strcat(c, reply);
            strcat(c, " | ");
            strcat(c, cmdStr->c_str());

            if((pipe = _popen(c, "r")) == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to create pipe!\n");
            }

           while(!feof(pipe))
           {
              if(fgets(pipeBuffer, 8192, pipe) != NULL)
              {
                  printf(pipeBuffer);
              }
           }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Although you are safe with the way you're using `feof()` (which is relatively unusual; congratulations), you are double checking for EOF unnecessarily.  It would be better and more idiomatic to replace the `while (!feof(pipe)) { if (fgets(pipeBuffer, 8192, pipe) != NULL) ...` with just `while (fgets(pipeBuffer, sizeof(pipeBuffer), pipe) != NULL) ...`.

Comment: One thing unclear from the question - is this writing to the command's stdin, and reading from its stdout, for a single execution of the command?  Or, do you just need an example of executing a command and sending data to it's standard input.

Comment: There is a pile of C++ in that C code...as well as a pile of C code in that C++ code.  Choose one language and work with it rather than with a hybrid of two languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it with this, just in case anyone else runs into a similar problem:

```
FILE* pipe;

if((pipe = _popen(cmdStr->c_str(), "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to create pipe!\n");
}

fprintf(pipe, "%s", reply);

printf("\nPipe process returned %d\n", _pclose(pipe));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if your application is already running as a console, you can use the function [system()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) that executes a command on CMD, if not, you can simulate a console using [AllocConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then using system(), if you want to really emulate, you can use [pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I wasn't allowed to use `system()` because this was for a Systems Programming assignment but I figured out a solution, see above answer :)